# subxt: How to derive serialize trait for runtime type?

Tags: subxt, serialization

I want to define a struct serializeable to json

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Struct {
    item: SomeRuntimeType,
}
```

but I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `pallet_pallet::types::SomeRuntimeType: conf::_::_serde::Serialize` is not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:150:10
     |
150  | #[derive(Serialize)]
     |          ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `conf::_::_serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `pallet_pallet::types::SomeRuntimeType`
```

Is there a way to derive some kind of serialization in subxt?

```rust
#[subxt::subxt(
    runtime_metadata_path = "res/metadata.scale",
    derive_for_all_types = "Debug" // <--- like adding Serialize here
)]
pub mod runtime {}
```

Or do I have to manually implement serialization?

Answer (score 1):

It probably won't work to derive `serde::Serialize` for all types in the subxt codegen because there are some types that doesn't implement `Serialize`.

For individual types you can try:

```rust
#[subxt::subxt(
    runtime_metadata_path = "artifacts/metadata.scale",
    derive_for_all_types = "Clone, Debug, Eq, PartialEq",
    derive_for_type(
        path = "pallet_election_provider_multi_phase::RoundSnapshot",
        derive = "Default, serde::Serialize"
    )
)]
pub mod runtime {}
```

If that won't work you need to provide your own Serialize impl/add wrapper struct, replace the type with your own or something similar.

I hope it helps